# Play framework, upgrade project to latest version

Tags: playframework-2.3

I try to search around but I couldn't find how to upgrade a playframework project to the latest playframework version.

For example my project has been created using playframework 2.3.4 and I wish to upgrade to 2.3.7.

Thanks.

Comment: You could read the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23) to migrate projects from `2.2` to `2.3` to get the basic steps, but I don't think that you need more than just install the newest framework and use your project with it. Don't forget to clean and re-build it after the update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're only upgrading from 2.3.4 to 2.3.7, literally all you should need to do is change the play version in your `plugins.sbt` file to 2.3.7.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.7")
```

And I guess for good measure run `activator clean`.

It's only a minor version upgrade, so between 2.3.x versions there are no breaking changes--only minor feature additions and bug fixes.

Comment: Didn't see the files in the project/ folder… Thanks !